# Extracting regex submatch boundaries without backtracking

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I'm attempting to develop from scratch a simple regex engine.  I would like for my engine to have the ability to report, "The regex matched on a substring of this line starting at index  and ending at index ."

It makes sense to me how to accomplish this using recursive backtracking.
However, I'd like my implementation of the search to use Thompson's multi-state approach.  Is this feasible?

Comment: Isn't the grep utility already doing that ?

Comment: You mean using the multi-state approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred to me after I made this post that I could store the states in a linked list format:

```
typedef struct stateRecord {
    struct stateRecord *next;
    size_t state;
    size_t startIdx;
    size_t endIdx;
} stateRecord;
```